# On the number of digits for irrational numerical base systems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to grasp an idea on irrational numerical base systems - namely base $\pi$, $e$ etc.

As I understand it from some articles, for a given base $b$ (integer or not) one would only need $[b] - 1$ ($[b]$ integer part of $b$) digits to represent a number. Like the number $(\pi)_{\pi} = 10$.

Here lies my confusion.
If base 8, requires 8 digits {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and base 16 requires 16 digits why does a base $\pi$ numerical system does not require '$\pi$' digits but only $[\pi]$ digits?

Comment: How does your article define "base $\pi$"?

Comment: I just edited, maybe that clears up the confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as base $10$ expands a number as a series of integer powers of $10$, base $\pi$ expands a number as a series of integer powers of $\pi$. The reason base $\pi$ only requires four digits (including zero) is because:

$$4\pi=12.5663...>\pi^2=9.8696...>3\pi=9.4247...~.$$

That is, we only need the four digits $\{0,1,2,3\}$ in base $\pi$ because any higher multiples of $\pi$ can just as easily be represented as a sum of higher powers of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks I really like your answer. It's enlightening and points straight to what I intended.